# I can't understand why displayAllTodoItems() is being executed twice in this code

Tags: javascript, node.js

The code given is of a console Todo application made in NodeJS that can store new Todo items, display them and will be able to delete any one item. The problem I'm facing is when I add a new Todo item into the application and then without stopping the program, I try to display all the Todo items stored by using `displayAllTodoItems()`, the results are displayed twice. But this does not happen if I execute `displayAllTodoItems()` after stopping the application once. Could anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

let outputData;
console.log(`Welcome to Todo app!
-----------------------------------
Press 1 to add a new Todo item.
Press 2 to display all Todo items.
Press 3 to delete a Todo item.
Press 4 to exit.`);
takeInput();

function takeInput(){
    rl.on("line", (answer) => {
        checkSwitch(answer);
    });
}

function checkSwitch(answer) {
    if(answer == "1"){
        rl.question("Give the name and description of the Todo item (separated by a comma):", (ans) => {
            let [name, description] = ans.split(",");
            addNewTodoItem(name, description);
        });   
    }
    else if(answer == "2"){
            displayAllTodoItems();
    }
    else if(answer == "3"){
        rl.question("Give the number of the Todo item to be deleted:", (ans) => {
            let number = ans;
            deleteATodoItem(number);
        });   
    }
    else if(answer == "4"){
        console.log("Program exited!")
        process.exit();
    }
    else {
        console.log("Invalid selection!")
    }
    takeInput();

}

const addNewTodoItem = (name, description) => {
    fs.readFile("todofile.txt", "UTF-8", (err) => {
        if(err){
            fs.writeFile("todofile.txt", `${name}:${description}\n`, (err) => {
                if(err){
                    console.log("The data couldn't be saved.");
                }
                else{
                    console.log("The Todo item has been saved.");
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            fs.appendFile("todofile.txt", `${name}:${description}\n`, (err) => {
                if(err){
                    console.log("The data couldn't be saved.");
                }
                else{
                    console.log("The Todo item has been saved.");
                }
            });
        }
    });   
}

const displayAllTodoItems = () => {
    let text = fs.readFileSync("todofile.txt").toString('utf-8').split("\n");
    text = text.filter(text=>text!="");
    text.forEach((element, i)=> {
        console.log(`${i+1}. ${element}`);
    })
}
const deleteATodoItem = () => console.log("Delete");
```

I've posted the answer to this question too.

Comment: Looks to me like `takeInput()` adds another event handler on each call. That won't remove the previous event handlers, so `checkSwitch()` will be called on every "line" event once for each time `takeInput()` has been called.

Comment: So, what is the possible solution? Thank you for responding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `takeInput()` function call within `checkSwitch()` was the cause of the problem. The issue has been solved. The `rl.on("line", callback)` was listening for new line entries once `takeInput()` function was executed in the beginning of the program. When `takeInput()` was called again in the `checkSwitch()` function, the `rl.on("line", callback)` was executed twice, creating the problem. Here is the complete and corrected version of the application:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

let outputData;
console.log(`Welcome to Todo app!
-----------------------------------
Press 1 to add a new Todo item.
Press 2 to display all Todo items.
Press 3 to delete a Todo item.
Press 4 to exit.`);

takeInput();

function takeInput() {
    rl.on("line", (answer) => {
        checkSwitch(answer);
    });
}

function checkSwitch(answer) {
    if (answer == "1") {
        rl.question("Give the name and description of the Todo item (separated by a comma):", (ans) => {
            let [name, description] = ans.split(",");
            addNewTodoItem(name, description);
        });
    }
    else if (answer == "2") {
        displayAllTodoItems();
    }
    else if (answer == "3") {
        rl.question("Give the number of the Todo item to be deleted:", (ans) => {
            deleteATodoItem(ans);

        });
    }
    else if (answer == "4") {
        console.log("Program exited!")
        process.exit();
    }
    else {
        console.log("Invalid selection!");
    }
}

const addNewTodoItem = (name, description) => {
    fs.readFile("todofile.txt", "UTF-8", (err) => {
        if (err) {
            fs.writeFileSync("todofile.txt", `${name}:${description}\n`);
            console.log("The Todo item has been saved.");
        }
        else {
            fs.appendFile("todofile.txt", `${name}:${description}\n`, (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("The data couldn't be saved.");
                }
                else {
                    console.log("The Todo item has been saved.");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

const displayAllTodoItems = () => {
    let text = fs.readFileSync("todofile.txt").toString('utf-8').split("\n");
    text = text.filter(text => text != "");
    text.forEach((element, i) => {
        console.log(`${i + 1}. ${element}`);
    });
}

const deleteATodoItem = (number) => {
    let text = fs.readFileSync("todofile.txt").toString('utf-8').split("\n");
    text = text.filter(text => text != "");
    text.splice(number - 1, 1);
    fs.writeFileSync("todofile.txt", text.join("\n"));
    console.log("Item deleted.");
}
```